# How would I solve these equations of motion? (Coupled Second Order PDEs or ODEs?)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

$\ddot{x}(t)=\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}$

$\ddot{y}(t)=\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}$

I have no idea where to start with something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider polar coordinates, $x+iy=re^{i\phi}$. Then
$$
\ddot r+2i\dot r\dot\phi+ir\ddot\phi-r\dot\phi^2=\frac1r
$$
so that, like in any radial field, $r^2\dot\phi=L$ with a constant angular moment $L$, and
$$
\ddot r=\frac1r+\frac{L^2}{r^3}=0.
$$
This can be integrated once again to
$$
E=\frac12\dot r^2-\ln(r)+\frac{L^2}{2r^2}
$$
with a constant energy $E$.

So one gets an acceleration away from the origin, which is higher with higher initial angular speed. The acceleration and angular speed go to zero the farther away the particle gets from the origin.

Comment: Is the tangential velocity constant?

Comment: would it be difficult to re-express this in terms of x(t) and y(t)?

Comment: No, the tangential velocity $\dot x+i\dot y=(\dot r+ir\dot\phi)e^{i\phi}=(\dot r+i\frac{L}{r})e^{i\phi}$ is not constant. You can always change back from polar coordinates to Cartesian coordinates. It will not look that nice, but also not overly complicated.